# Preconfigure installation to work with most network cards and drivers

Tags: networking, drivers, server

I am trying to build a black box ubuntu server installation complete with all required software (including custom) on a hard drive. My deployment systems are in a remote area with limited internet access and even less technical knowledge support.

I am able to build and package everything on my local machine using a HD dock and the drive is ready for shipping.

My only concern is networking. I am not sure of what network card the servers will have. All I know for sure is that there are no DHCP servers so I need to configure for static IP which I am able to do with eth0.

Since there are no guarantees (to my knowledge) that the network will be called eth0 (depending on controller), any suggestions on how to ensure that my network setup will work on most generic network cards?

Regards,
Pierre

Comment: Almost all Ethernet cards that matters are supported. WiFi not so much. Unless you're running a very new chipset there's nothing you need to do.

Comment: I originally had configured eth0 to have a static ip, couple of days ago, the system motherboard was problematic and it was changed. The system booted correctly but no connection. After an hour or so over a phone (blind as a bat), I figured out that the network interface is now called p2p1 instead of eth0. Changing the /etc/network/interfaces file eth0 to p2p1 fixed the problem. I am trying to avoid this issue in the future.